# Rotating positional audio in SceneKit when playing from SKVideoNode

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, scenekit, avplayeritem

I am writing a 360º VR experience using SceneKit. It displays video in a dome around the user.

A SpriteKit scene is playing the video feed using an SKVideoNode. This SpriteKit scene is wrapped around a sphere, in SceneKit, creating the dome, thus:

```
videoGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = spriteKitScene
```

Playback is great; I see 360º video and I hear audio. I'd like to add positional audio so that when the user spins around, the sound moves around with them. Not moving position, but rotating with the user's head (Oculus Rift-like).

How can I do that?

Some research:

- Ideally I could tell SpriteKit my rotation.
- Next best would be a way to access the audio tracks (e.g. 6 tracks in an MP4 with 5.1 audio) and attach each track to a node in the 3D scene.
- SpriteKit and SceneKit both support positional audio.
- `SKScene` has a `listener` property. But being in a 2D world, SKNode doesn't know about rotation; I can't set my current head rotation.
- SceneKit has the `audioListener` node, which I *can* tell my head rotation. But that expects a `SCNAudioPlayer` which I don't have - SKVideoNode is playing the video & audio. If only I could tell the SCNAudioPlayer about the SKVideoNode's audio tracks!
- `SKScene` also offers `audioEngine` - are the tracks available from here?
- There's no SCNVideoNode, so I have to use SKVideoNode.

Is there a way to do positional audio in this situation?

Comment: Did you come to a solution to this? Splitting the 5.1 tracks into separate audio nodes will work, although its cumbersome.

Comment: No solution, but I opened a Radar requesting it. You could do the same, perhaps that will help.